# Eclipse: The context menu in “Display View” does not open

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Eclipse: The context menu in “Display View” does not open.
The context menu used to open when a dot is put after a variable,
but now it has stopped working.

I have tried ctrl + space after dot, but still the context menu does not open.

Comment: This usually happens when a plugin throws an error. Look in your `${eclipse_workspace}/.metadata/.log` for exceptions, then remove/update the plugin causing the error.

Comment: Created a new workspace, then it worked fine. Thanks